# R data.table append one column to another, covert list to csv

Tags: r

New to R, I have a csv file containing two columns of string. I read them in using

`keyword_notes<-fread(file_path, skip=1, header=FALSE)`

And got something like:

```
      V1              V2
"I love apple"     "I love peach"
```

I want to append the second column to the first making the whole df like:

```
    V1
"I love apple"
"I love peach"
```

Then I have some code to count the word frequency in those strings
The result is a list like:

```
 $`1`
    apple peach  love
    154    124     93
```

How can I save these results into a csv file with two columns like this:

```
apple  154
peach  124
love    93
```

Again, my question is how to append the 2nd column to the 1st and how to save the results into csv.
These seem to be really easy operations but I'm new to R and searched online but didn't find similar questions.

```
keyword_notes<-fread(file_path, skip=1, header=FALSE)
out_df <- data.frame(V1 = unlist(keyword_notes, use.names = FALSE))
mydata <- Corpus(VectorSource(keyword_notes))
mydata <- tm_map(mydata, content_transformer(tolower))
mydata <- tm_map(mydata, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
mydata <- tm_map(mydata, removePunctuation)
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(mydata)
fre_list <- findMostFreqTerms(dtm, n = 10L)
```

structure(list(V1 = c("There is a typo in the Avantor TransAmerica file. The agent number in the config is \"\"RT111215\"\", and it should be \"\"TR111215\"\". I need someone to update the config.",), V2 = c("Retro Rules", "Advised to create a task to Chris Kaiser's Team.",)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like two separate questions. For the first one, you can `unlist` the dataframe

```
out_df <- data.frame(V1 = unlist(keyword_notes, use.names = FALSE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
out_df

#            V1
#1 I love apple
#2 I love peach
```

where `df` is

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1L, .Label = "I love apple", class = "factor"),
V2 = structure(1L, .Label = "I love peach", class = "factor")), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), 
.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x102012ee0>)
```

for second, use `stack`

```
out_df <- stack(lst[[1]])
out_df

#  values   ind
#1    154 apple
#2    124 peach
#3     93  love
```

where `lst` is

```
lst <- list(`1` = c(apple = 154,  peach = 124,  love = 93))
```

You can write them to csv using `write.csv`

```
write.csv(out_df, "path/of/the/file.csv")
```

Comment: Something weird happened, when I check your out_df, the result is what I wanted, but somehow it breaks my word frequency count code.
using library(tm)

mydata <- Corpus(VectorSource(keyword_notes))
mydata <- tm_map(mydata, content_transformer(tolower))
mydata <- tm_map(mydata, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
mydata <- tm_map(mydata, removePunctuation)
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(mydata)
fre_list <- findMostFreqTerms(dtm, n = 1000L)

if I replace the first line keyword_notes with out_df, the output only contains numbers

Comment: @Dylan The word frequency and `keyword_notes` are two different objects, right? `df` and `lst` as I have shown ? Maybe change the name and use `out_df1`, `out_df1 <- stack(fre_list[[1]])`

Comment: Sorry, the code in comment looks messy so I edited the question, I have copy pasted the full code. I haven't reached the out_df1 <- stack  part yet. I will first need to get the word frequency count by the code above. But if I replace the keyword_notes with out_df, the word frequency count code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The code with `unlist` appends all the column of dataframe into single column. Also shouldn't you use `mydata <- Corpus(VectorSource(out_df))` instead of `keyword_notes` ?

Comment: Yes, I was using mydata <- Corpus(VectorSource(out_df)), but this output looks weird like: 
197  376  550  767  984  100 1000 1001 1002 1003 
   2    2    2    2    2    1    1    1    1    1
While when I was using  mydata <- Corpus(VectorSource(keyword_notes)):
advised             plan             file            issue             need 
    216               97                75               65                 64

Comment: When I check in Rstudio, the variable of out_df looks totally fine, it is what we expected to see.

Comment: Hmmm...I am not sure what happens in `Corpus(VectorSource...` part of the code. Can you update the post with `dput(head(keyword_notes))` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200206/discussion-between-dylan-and-ronak-shah).